# How do I use a new framework I have built?

Tags: objective-c

I have had some issues with the AWS IOS SDK framekit, since it was not built to work with OSX apps.  I found a [modified version of the SDK that Brad Larson created](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/aws-ios-sdk-0.1.0-mac.zip).

The directory structure looks something like:

```
AWSiOSSDK.framework/
src/
--Amazon.Runtime/
--Amazon.S3/
..
--AWSCocoa/
----AWSCocoa_Prefix.pch
----AWSCocoa.xcodeproj
----etc
--include/
```

So if I go into the xcode project, and build AWSCocoa it compiles.  But when I look at the timestamp on the AWSiOSSDK.framework, it hasn't changed.  So I don't know what compiling this AWSCocoa gets me, or where I can find the files it creates.  So assuming that building AWSCocoa.xcodeproj is supposed to build a new version of the framework compatible with OSX development, where do I find and link what I've built?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AWSiOSSDK.framework bundle is a precompiled framework, probably left over from my earlier experiments in making a Mac version of this (since you can't use frameworks like this with iOS, only static libraries).  Ignore that.

If you are using Xcode 4, your built framework will be created somewhere in your `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/` directory.  To find where it lies, go to your project navigator in Xcode 4, expand the Products group, right click on AWSCocoa.framework, and select Show in Finder.  This is no different from any other third-party framework you would compile.

Nominally, you'll want to add this framework as a target dependency in your application so that it is built alongside that.  You'll also have to make sure that the framework is copied into the appropriate location within your application bundle so that it can be used by your application at runtime.

Comment: And thanks for releasing your modifications to this framework.